Excel Date "Ctrl + F" failure
I have the following dates in row 3 as per image at the bottom of the question.  The format of the cell is: "dd/mm/yy hh:mm".
The formula in C1 is "='LR PREP'!B884+TIME(1,0,0)" and D1 to W1 is "=C3+TIME(1,0,0)".
The issue I am having is whenever I search for the date (using Ctrl + F or VBA) I can't find the date & time required.  For example, if I search for "08/07/2024  07:00:00" I would expect it to find it in L3 but no success.
Any support or nudges in the correct direction appreciated.


I thought it would be something text based but that is why I am stuck and reaching out for support.  Searching for the formula isn't really practical or of any use.
In short I want to look at the current time using now() function (rounding up to nearest hour).  I would then search for that date / time in row 3 and select that cell.
Hope that helps explain what I am after?

Options -> Look in set to Values have you tried?

Sure did "Black Cat".  Thanks for the suggestion though.

What if you first nest your formula inside TEXT() and add your date format argument?

Why not get the serial number that all dates are stored as and search for that?

@bugdrown this works a treat.  Feel free to put as the answer.

@SolarMike I did try this and went round in more circles.

Try nesting your formula inside the TEXT() function and using the appropriate argument for your date/time format, like this:
 TEXT([your formula for date/time], 
      "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")

Reference: https://exceljet.net/formulas/convert-date-to-text

I was able to reproduce the error on Windows once, but when tried it again it seems to work - will keep checking…


Maybe this is a "windows" feature? lol

Hmm... seems to work there too.

I was wrong - I see the error now when I enter the formulas as you described. Sorry about it. I'll investigate further ;)

No apology needed :) apparently text() solves the issue.

Good! I saw the error once, but when I cleared the cells (the highlighted) and re-entered the formula matching yours, Find worked as expected. Puzzling.
